# Extjs record in window constructor config, when destroyed subfields data is lost

Tags: extjs

I have an Extjs window, which recieves a Model/Record as part of the config as follows:

```
 var myModel = Ext.create('App.model.MyModel', { ... });

var window = new Ext.widget('mywindow',{
            myModel: myModel,
        });
```

myModel is a record with the following assotiation:

```
{type: 'hasMany', model: 'App.model.OtherModel', name: 'othermodel'},
```

The othermodel has fields and subfields as follows:

```
{name:'regular_field',type: 'string'},
{name:'subfield_main',type: 'json', fields:[
            {name:'subfield1', type:'string'},
            {name:'subfield2', type:'string'}
        ]},
```

After the window is destroyed, I obtain the reference to myModel.
I can access the othermodel store and obtain the first othermodel instance OK.
But the problem is it doesn't have any data on the subfield_main!!! Although it has the data on regular_field.

What can be causing this behavior??? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line. It was not an Extjs issue.
Inspired on Christoph suggestion, I started listening to the store datachanged event.
After watching closely when the event was called and the Network tab in Chrome Debugging Console I managed to locate the issue, which was actually in my backend code. It wasn't returning the data needed to populate the

```
 {name:'subfield_main',type: 'json', fields:[
            {name:'subfield1', type:'string'},
            {name:'subfield2', type:'string'}
        ]},
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a nested field definition for subfield_main. There is no such feature [documented](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field).  You can use a mapping instead:

```
{name:'regular_field',type: 'string'},
{name:'subfield1',type: 'string', mapping: 'subfield_main.subfield1'},
{name:'subfield2',type: 'string', mapping: 'subfield_main.subfield2'},
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tryied the mapping and even tryied changing the subfield_main to an association with a third model, and unfortunately got the same result. Now OtherModel has an association with a ThirdModel: {type: 'hasMany', model: 'App.model.ThirdModel', name: 'thirdmodels'}, The thirdmodelsStore is created and populated OK the first time. But after the window is closed, the thirdmodelsStore has no records, aka. same behaviour. – cualit 28 mins ago

Comment: You can try to set a breakpoint to the clear function of the store and look at the stacktrace, maybe you can see who empties the store. If you are using Ext Js 4.2.1 and a buffered store you could set the breakpoint to Store.js, line 2329, onPageMapClear.

Comment: Christoph thanks for your suggestion. I'm using Ext 4.0.7, but you inspired me to listen to the store datachanged event! After watching closely when the event was called and the Network tab in Chrome Debugging Console I managed to locate the issue (which was actually in my backend code and not on Extjs!). Thanks again for the help! I tryed to vote up your answer but since I'm a rookie here I wasn't allowed to do so.